# Simple and most effective approach for grids in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using webgrid at present, but finding limitations so seeking you experience on a good self contained solution that fit the MVC model neatly and simple especially model binding and validation annotations.

My options at present are:

1) Server based: Syncfusion HTML Helper server grid controls.

2) Telerik Kendo Client side JQuery controls

3) Other Telerik controls.

4) Standard JQuery grids.

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking into Kendo MVC wrapper. They are simple to use + they can really speed up your development.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this:

jqGrid: jQuery Grid Plugin or

DataTables (table plug-in for jQuery)